# JS Puzzle - Initialization of images and game start function problems

Tags: javascript, html, project

I'm currently working on a little project and I am stuck on a little bit of code that I have just been trying different methods and isn't panning out as well as I'd like it to be.

Basically, I have made the UI for the puzzle (12 square grid) and set the properties of those tiles through CSS. I am planning on making this game a sliding puzzle game, meaning that one tile is blank and should be swapped with other tiles when clicked on and the aim of the game is to make the image whole. I'm about to get to writing the Javascript to make it all work, I have made an array of variables for the rows/columns and made a link tag (a href) to initiate the game through a function and including the onclick events on each tile. I need to also make JS code for the user to win the game given the tiles are in the correct order but I have some ideas for that.

I'm just struggling on the easiest way to do this and get the image(s) to display and split up on each tile randomly. I tried to include a math. function in an earlier build of this but this did not work out for me (probably because I did it wrong).

Any help would be appreciated and if you need more information regarding this, then don't hesitate to ask.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ryfR1Cqk (updated link)

```
 <script type="javascript/text">
    var gamearray = column = row = board = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',''];
```

Comment: What do you need help for?  With what I have read, you need us to tell you the complete solution for your game. Do you have any actual code that we could see to help you? If so tell us what is not working as expected please :)

Comment: @floverdevel Hey, I just need help getting the images referenced in the CSS portion of the project to be mixed up through the 12 tiles at random, and allow the blank tile to be moved around the board by selecting the tile next to it and swapping it with that tile until the image is completed. (should be a paste bin with complete code above?)

Comment: You have a call to a function named "tileClick" ... Can you us this function?

Comment: @floverdevel The tileClick event is going to be used to handle the specific tile being clicked, find the valid position for it to move to and make the move (might need to make a function to draw the whole board again). I was more refering to making something in JS so the .tileimage1 and .tileimage2 get mixed into the tiles if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below example

```js
// https://www.sitepoint.com/image-manipulation-with-html5-canvas-a-sliding-puzzle-2/

init();

// random values in boxes; insert values and add classnames
function init() {
  var puzzleValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,  ""],
      $puzzleBox = $(".puzzle");
  $puzzleBox.html("");
  for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
    var $newDiv = $("<div>");
    let numb = random(puzzleValues);
    $newDiv.html(numb);
    $newDiv.addClass("items item"+numb);
    $puzzleBox.append($newDiv);
  }
  $(".item").css("background-image", "none");
  $puzzleItems = $(".items");
  move();
}

// on every move, check if the game is won
function check() {
  let checkArr = [];
  for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if ($(".items").eq(i).hasClass("item"+(i+1))) {
      checkArr.push(i+1);
    //  console.log(checkArr);
    }
  }
  if (checkArr.length === 8) {
    $(".item").css("background-image", "url(https://res.cloudinary.com/beumsk/image/upload/v1513108563/tiger_veeob8.jpg)");
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You won !");
      init();
    }, 200);
  }
}

// takes random element af an array and deletes it
function random(arr) {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  let toReturn = arr[rand];
  arr.splice(rand, 1);
  return toReturn; 
}

// change 2 elts positions in DOM
function swapElts(elt1, elt2) {
  var $temp = $("<div>");
  elt1.before($temp);
  elt2.before(elt1);
  $temp.before(elt2);
  $temp.remove;
}

// on click, move this box to the 'empty' box
function move() {
  $(".items").on("click", function(e) {
    // item 0
    if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(0))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(1).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(1));
      else if ($(".items").eq(3).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(3));
    }
    // item 1
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(1))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(0).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(0));
      else if ($(".items").eq(2).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(2));
      else if ($(".items").eq(4).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(4));
    }
    // item 2
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(2))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(1).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(1));
      else if ($(".items").eq(5).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(5));
    }
    // item 3
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(3))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(0).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(0));
      else if ($(".items").eq(4).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(4));
      else if ($(".items").eq(6).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(6));
    }
    // item 4
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(4))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(1).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(1));
      else if ($(".items").eq(3).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(3));
      else if ($(".items").eq(5).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(5));
      else if ($(".items").eq(7).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(7));
    }
    // item 5
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(5))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(2).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(2));
      else if ($(".items").eq(4).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(4));
      else if ($(".items").eq(8).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(8));
    }
    // item 6
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(6))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(3).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(3));
      else if ($(".items").eq(7).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(7));
    }
    // item 7
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(7))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(4).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(4));
      else if ($(".items").eq(6).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(6));
      else if ($(".items").eq(8).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(8));
    }
    // item 8
    else if ($(this).is($(".items").eq(8))) {
      if      ($(".items").eq(5).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(5));
      else if ($(".items").eq(7).hasClass("item")) swapElts($(this), $(".items").eq(7));
    }
    // perform the check
    check();
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #e53935, #5e35b1);
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.puzzle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 302px;
  min-height: 302px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: solid 1px white;
  margin: auto;
}
.puzzle .items {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/beumsk/image/upload/v1513108563/tiger_veeob8.jpg);
  background-size: 300%;
}
.puzzle .item1 {
  background-position: top left;
}
.puzzle .item2 {
  background-position: top;
}
.puzzle .item3 {
  background-position: top right;
}
.puzzle .item4 {
  background-position: center left;
}
.puzzle .item5 {
  background-position: center;
}
.puzzle .item6 {
  background-position: center right;
}
.puzzle .item7 {
  background-position: bottom left;
}
.puzzle .item8 {
  background-position: bottom;
}
.puzzle .item {
  background-position: bottom right;
}

footer {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffe082;
}
footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="puzzle"></section>
```

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you if this is okay :)